# Rstudio Time sum calculation

Tags: r

How can I sum the total time per driver in R? Can someone help me?

[image]

[Total time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxlrT.png)
[Prefered end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0iBc.png)

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `summarize(mydf, across(Bottas:Vettel, sum))`

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation to make: please do not use images to share data. Instead, use `dput()` of your data frame. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible example on SO.

One approach to this involves the `tidyverse` and `lubridate` packages (I am sure there are other solutions).

First, would put your data into long form instead of wide. The times are then converted from `%H:%M:%OS` (with milliseconds) to durations since midnight.

Then, for each driver, these times are summed up, and results are provided in different formats:

1. `total_time1` - total number of seconds (with decimal places)
2. `total_time2` - number minutes (M) and the number decimal seconds (S)
3. `total_time3` - total time in `%M:%OS` format (minutes and decimal seconds)

**Edit**: In addition, I have added two columns based on OP request:

1. `total_time_minutes` - total number of minutes (with decimal places)
2. `avg_speed` - average speed in km/hr, assuming 27.004,65 meters

I hope this is helpful. Please let me know.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -lap) %>%
  mutate(lap_time = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(value, format = "%H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC")) -
           as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), tz = "UTC"))) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(total_time1 = sum(lap_time)) %>%
  mutate(total_time2 = seconds_to_period(total_time1),
         total_time3 = sprintf("%d:%.4f", minute(total_time2), second(total_time2)),
         total_time_minutes = total_time1/60,
         avg_speed = 3.6 * 27004.65/total_time1) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

**Output**

```
        name total_time1          total_time2 total_time3 total_time_minutes avg_speed
1     Bottas     319.782 5M 19.7815999984741S   5:19.7816            5.32969   304.010
2   Hamilton     320.320 5M 20.3204002380371S   5:20.3204            5.33867   303.498
3    Leclerc     319.981   5M 19.98140001297S   5:19.9814            5.33302   303.820
4 Verstappen     318.220  5M 18.219899892807S   5:18.2199            5.30366   305.502
5     Vettel     318.625 5M 18.6247997283936S   5:18.6248            5.31041   305.114
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(lap = 1:5, Bottas = c("00:01:04.9388", "00:01:03.7164", 
"00:01:04.0028", "00:01:03.3424", "00:01:03.7812"), Hamilton = c("00:01:04.5280", 
"00:01:03.7524", "00:01:03.9632", "00:01:04.3712", "00:01:03.7056"
), Leclerc = c("00:01:04.9812", "00:01:03.7740", "00:01:04.6026", 
"00:01:03.3920", "00:01:03.2316"), Verstappen = c("00:01:04.1704", 
"00:01:03.7383", "00:01:03.7128", "00:01:02.8460", "00:01:03.7524"
), Vettel = c("00:01:04.3632", "00:01:02.8244", "00:01:03.7164", 
"00:01:03.8532", "00:01:03.8676")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Do you know how I can calculate the average speed per second or hour? For example,  it took Verstappen 318.2199 seconds to drive 27.004,65 meters (5 laps). I also added a new picture called "Total time" in my first post.

Comment: My final result should look like "prefered end result" in my first post. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @BIDATA Please see edited answer with time in minutes and average speed in km/hr